# Back and forth, to and fro , what should be the proposition after?

Tags: prepositions

Eg:

> I had to carry it back and forth _ the office

Is it to the office or from the office or to and from the office?
Similarly for to and fro?

Comment: *back and forth* really needs two locations. "I had to carry it back and forth *between* the office and the repair shop."

Comment: One or both of the two locations can be implied. It will be either **here** and **there** or **there** and **there**.  It does not have to be explicit.  **from** or **to** would be correct preposition in that case, depending on which has been implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All of these work, but have slightly different implications - except "to and fro"**

---

Firstly, to take something "back and forth" suggests two locations, although one of these may be implicit. As such, regardless of which choice of direction - you will likely be implying:

> I had to carry it back and forth between the office and [where I am now, my house or some far away place]

Of course, the surrounding conversation is likely to give this context for this - but it's worth being aware of if you do wish to tell somebody an explicit location to emphasize how far you went.

---

The difference between "to" and "from" here, is where it implies you started.

- If you started at the office, you would be carrying it "back and forth, **from** the office".
- If you started outside the office, you would be carrying it "back and forth, **to** the office".

The full implied sentence would be:

> I had to carry it back and forth to the office from the other place.
>   or
>    I had to carry it back and forth from the office to the other place.

It's worth noting though, that mostly people won't care for the details in a situation like this. They care about the struggle of you carrying things between to distant locations - not the exact direction you took things (or even if you actually carried things in both directions). **As such, it doesn't really matter in most conversations which of the two words you choose (even if it's not "correct").**

---

The alternative "to and from" would also be correct here. However it does lead to a different tone of sentence.

> I had to carry it back and forth, to and from the office.

This is perfectly correct, and again has an implicit second location. The difference here is the repetition of a phrase similar to "back and forth", adds emphasis to the phrase (likely emphasis on how it was tiring or a lot of work, but your tone will dictate that).

As this is a idiomatic phrase, there's no implied starting or ending direction - it will always be "to and from", never the other way around.

---

However, the phrase "to and fro" will not work here. Unlike "to" and "from" which specify directions - this phrase specifies a type of movement.

As such, the sentence:

> I had to carry it back and forth, to and fro the office.

Does not fit particularly well.

If you wanted to use this to add additional emphasis onto the phrase - to show much much moving you had to do, it could be integrated as:

> I had to carry it back and forth, to and fro between the office and PlaceName.

However, using these idioms together will make the sentence sound a little jarring and it's not a phrase many native speakers would use in this way.

Of note though, you could replace "back and forth" with "to and fro" - as they mean the same thing.

Comment: Are back and forth prepositions?

Comment: @Ice "to" or "from" are prepositions, while "back and forth" is an adjective - describing a certain way of moving. (more info: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/back-and-forth)